# Gitlab CI run different tests parallel

Tags: gradle, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a project that needs to run integration tests in different environments (Postgres, Oracle etc)

For this I created different tasks where I set the environment-variables differently based on the db like:

```
task postgresqlIntegrationTest(type: Test, group: "Verification", description: "Runs integration tests on postgresql.") {
    dependsOn compileTestJava
    mustRunAfter test

    environment "env", "postgresql"

      useJUnitPlatform {
        filter {
            includeTestsMatching "*IT"
        }
    }
}
```

Which works without problems.

Now I would like to run those tasks parallel which I currently configured in my .gitlab-ci.yml file like this:

```
image: docker

variables:
  BUILD_ID: "job# $CI_JOB_ID"
  GIT_COMMIT: $CI_COMMIT_SHA
  GIT_BRANCH: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME

stages:
  - test

test:unit:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - ls -la
    - git status
    - git config --global user.name "Git Lab"
    - ./gradlew test --stacktrace --info

test:h2:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - ls -la
    - git status
    - git config --global user.name "Git Lab"
    - ./gradlew h2IntegrationTest--stacktrace --info

test:postgres:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - ls -la
    - git status
    - git config --global user.name "Git Lab"
    - ./gradlew postgresqlIntegrationTest --stacktrace --info

test:oracle:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - ls -la
    - git status
    - git config --global user.name "Git Lab"
    - ./gradlew oracleIntegrationTest --stacktrace --info
```

However this causes the steps "testClasses", "compileTestJava", "classes" etc to run for each of the the parallel tasks which seems like a waste. Is there any way where I can execute those base-tasks before and then use them in the "test"-stage?

Do I still need to run `gradlew build` or are my tasks equal when I run all the test?

What is the proper way to make the integration tests parallel?